# OpenVPN server with two tap interfaces, how to allow tap0 to see tap1

Tags: openvpn, tap

I'm new to OpenVPN but have managed to install it on an Ubuntu machine. The requirement is to allow Mikrotik and then laptop clients to connect to the VPN. I managed to make this work by running two openvpn servers on the same machine, one configured to `proto tcp` and one for `proto udp` each listening on different ports. The tcp version uses `10.8.0.0/24` and the udp version uses `10.9.0.0/24`.

If I do an `ifconfig` on the Ubuntu server I see `eth0`, `tap0` and `tap1`. The Mikrotik can connect to the VPN and the laptops can connect to the VPN via the respective ports and have proper connectivity.

How can I allow devices on `tap0`, ie. network `10.8.0.0/24` to see devices on `tap1`, ie. network `10.9.0.0/24`.

Will bridging `tap0` and `tap1` work, and if so how can that be done. Or how is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set route on servers for your clients so they could know about other subnet(s). Since you did not mentioned OpenVPN version I suppose you are using 2.4.x.

If you are using custom client configuration on both servers so your clients can have static IP assigned, in server configuration:

```
option client_config_dir '/path/to/openvpn/client/directory'
```

Each client can have configuration which after connecting OpenVPN will look for client name as the client's X509 common name, [OpenVPN manual](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage).

Lats say that your Mikrotik client have X509 common name `Mikrotik`, you will add to `/path/to/openvpn/client/directory/Mikrotik` as follows

```
ifconfig-push 10.8.0.101 255.255.255.0
iroute 10.9.0.0 255.255.255.0
```

This will ensure that your Mikrotik will get address `10.8.0.101` and internal route `10.9.0.0` with netmask `255.255.255.0`

On same server (`10.8.0.0/24`) you need to push routes

```
list push 'route 10.9.0.0 255.255.255.0'
```

Same thing would need to be done for laptops VPN with changing IP addresses in server configuration.

Please note that you also need to allow forwarding on your server.